# Android StudioのtextInputLayoutが使えない

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

Android studioでtextInputLayoutを使用する方法を教えてください。
googleで調べたところすでにサポートが終了しているみたいなので代わりになるようなものを教えてください

Answer (score 0):

こんにちは、はじめまして。

TextInputLayoutは現在androidx内のmaterialコンポーネントのひとつとして利用できます。過去のsupportライブラリに入っていたものは利用できないと思います。

下記のGithubからプロジェクトをダウンロードしてプロジェクトを読み込んで、動作確認してみてください。**catalog** アプリから確認されるのがお勧めです。**io.material.catalog.textfield** の配下に利用例が確認できると思います。

https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android

利用法自体はgradleにライブラリを追加して用いる、今となってはシンプルなスタイルです。

https://material.io/develop/android/docs/getting-started

### 参照URL

https://material.io/
https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/classes
https://qiita.com/ehuthon-kd/items/7fb9b8c88ef6f040a7bf